# Multiple values stored in one column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have a table that contains a column with settings, they're formatted like:

> setting_name=setting_value|setting_name=setting_value|setting_name=setting_value

The thing is that it varies a lot on which settings have been filled. I would like to split all values and store them in a better way.

Currently it looks like this:

[image]

And I would like it to be:

[image]

To get there I used a function to split the values. Then I union them together and use a substring to get the setting_value that belongs to the setting_name. This is what I got so far:

```
/*
create function [dbo].[split_to_columns](@text varchar(8000)
                                            , @column tinyint
                                            , @separator char(1))
returns varchar(8000)
as
  begin
       declare @pos_start int = 1
       declare @pos_end int = charindex(@separator, @text, @pos_start)
       while (@column > 1 and @pos_end > 0)
         begin
             set @pos_start = @pos_end + 1
             set @pos_end = charindex(@separator, @text, @pos_start)
             set @column = @column - 1
         end 
       if @column > 1  set @pos_start = len(@text) + 1
       if @pos_end = 0 set @pos_end = len(@text) + 1 
       return substring(@text, @pos_start, @pos_end - @pos_start)
  end
*/

create table #settings(id int, setting varchar(255))
 insert into #settings(id, setting) values(1,'setting1=a|setting2=b|setting3=c')
 insert into #settings(id, setting) values(2,'setting1=d|setting2=e')
 insert into #settings(id, setting) values(3,'setting1=f|setting3=g')
 insert into #settings(id, setting) values(4,'setting2=h')

;
with cte as ( 
      select id, dbo.split_to_columns(setting, 1, '|') as setting from #settings
union select id, dbo.split_to_columns(setting, 2, '|') from #settings
union select id, dbo.split_to_columns(setting, 3, '|') from #settings
)
select distinct 
       x.id
     , (select substring(setting, charindex('=', setting) + 1, 255) from cte where setting like 'setting1=%' and id = x.id) as setting1 
     , (select substring(setting, charindex('=', setting) + 1, 255) from cte where setting like 'setting2=%' and id = x.id) as setting2  
     , (select substring(setting, charindex('=', setting) + 1, 255) from cte where setting like 'setting3=%' and id = x.id) as setting3 
  from cte x

drop table #settings
```

Am I doing this in the right way? I can't help myself thinking that I am making it too complex. Though I am not a big fan of the way my settings are formatted right now, I do see it more often. Which means that more people have to do this trick...

**Edit:**

I am importing picture-properties into a database. The settings mentioned above are the picture-properties and the id is the name of the picture the settings belong to.

Example of settings in one column:

> FullName=D:\8.jpg|FolderName=D:\|FileName=8.jpg|Size=7284351|Extension=.jpg|datePictureTaken=10-3-2017
> 11:53:38|ApertureValue=2|DateTime=10-3-2017
> 11:53:38|DateTimeDigitized=10-3-2017
> 11:53:38|DateTimeOriginal=10-3-2017
> 11:53:38|ExposureTime=0,0025706940874036|FocalLength=3,65|GPSAltitude=43|GPSDateStamp=10-3-2017
> 0:00:00|Model=QCAM-AA|ShutterSpeedValue=8,604

This is the reason I would like to have it formatted in the way described above.

Comment: The problem is that your data violates 1NF by storing multiple values like this. As such you have to parse this into something usable. Your splitter is not a great one. There are several other ways of splitting strings that don't need loops. My personal choice can be found here. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/ There are several other excellent examples here. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Comment: Your proposed architecture is only half way to being normalized. You should have each setting be on its own row.

Comment: @Sean Lange: Thanks, I will definetly test and try the other split functions from your links. And will post the fastest one (in this case) later on in this post. I see your point on normalization. But I like it this way because we're talking image_settings here. Id is the 'name' of a picture, settings could be for instance width and length.

Comment: Ahh then it just your example that is funky. In the real table your columns would be something like ID, Width, Height etc...that makes perfect sense.

Comment: @Sean Lange: Indeed :-) I just did an edit to the post itself so that less people get misled by my example.

Comment: I would do this in a framework like .NET

Answer (score 2):

I would convert the text into a basic chunk of XML so that we can then take a set-based approach to transforming the data into the results you want:

```
declare @settings table(id int, setting varchar(255))
insert into @settings (id,setting) values
(1,'setting1=a|setting2=b|setting3=c'),
(2,'setting1=d|setting2=e'),
(3,'setting1=f|setting3=g'),
(4,'setting2=h')

;with Xmlised (id,detail) as (
    select id,CONVERT(xml,'<prob><setting name="' +
        REPLACE(
            REPLACE(setting,'=','">'),
        '|','</setting><setting name="') + '</setting></prob>')
    from @settings
), shredded as (
    select
        x.id,
        S.value('./@name','varchar(50)') as name,
        S.value('./text()[1]','varchar(100)') as value
    from
        Xmlised x
            cross apply
        detail.nodes('prob/setting') as T(S)
)
select
    id,setting1,setting2,setting3
from
    shredded
        pivot (MAX(value) for name in (setting1,setting2,setting3)) u
```

Hopefully I've broken it into enough steps that you can see what it's doing and how.

Results:

```
id          setting1  setting2  setting3
----------- --------- --------- ---------
1           a         b         c
2           d         e         NULL
3           f         NULL      g
4           NULL      h         NULL
```

As Sean suggested in the comments though, I'd normally not consider storing the pivotted result and would generally skip that step

Comment: Thank you Damian_The_Unbeliever, this is exactly what I was hoping for, a whole different approach. With your shredding the code is nicely reduced, I hope it will also work faster.

Comment: It works, fast too, but I have a data error. When used on the complete set SQL Server returns a "illegal name character" error. I excluded <>/, what character could be bothering me?

Comment: @Steef - probably occurring during the XML transform. So look at characters with meaning in XML. My first guess would be a double quote in a setting name? Also ampersands.

Comment: I excluded them and was able to run it on the full set. Took about twelve minutes for 115k rows, way faster than my original code. (twelve minutes in SSMS, will be faster after rewriting to ´into´)

Answer (score 0):

WITH is pretty slow. I would suggest table that would store setting name, value, and some kind of group id. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[settings_table](
    [id] [int] NULL,
    [group] [int] NULL,
    [name] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [value] [nchar](10) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I don't know exactly what your program is doing with those settings, but this structure would be much more efficient in long run.

Comment: Hi Tomek, I did an edit to the question with an example of the settings. What should I store in the groupid? Is your comment regarding the normalization or can i use this groupid later on?

Comment: Walking is "pretty slow". There are definitely faster modes of transport. But whether or not that's a reason to rule out walking for any particular transport problem is highly context specific. Personally, I've not experienced any performance issues with queries using `WITH` so you ought to probably back up your assertion with some references which (would hopefully) supply some much needed context

Comment: He has char, date, and integer values.  Original post was not clear on this.

Comment: Hi Steef, i sugested group column, beacuse i saw that you got the same settings name in different records, so i thought that you need different values for the same setting name.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following 3 steps:

1) Create a generic Split function. This is the one I use:

```
CREATE FUNCTION Split(
     @StringToSplit VARCHAR(MAX)
    ,@Delimiter VARCHAR(10)
) 

RETURNS @SplitResult TABLE (id int, item VARCHAR(MAX))
BEGIN

    DECLARE @item VARCHAR(8000)
    DECLARE @counter int = 1

    WHILE CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @StringToSplit,0) <> 0
    BEGIN

        SELECT
            @item = RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@StringToSplit,1, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@StringToSplit,0)-1))),
            @StringToSplit = RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@StringToSplit, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@StringToSplit,0) + LEN(@Delimiter), LEN(@StringToSplit))))

        IF LEN(@item) > 0
            INSERT INTO @SplitResult SELECT @counter, @item

        SET @counter = @counter + 1
    END

    IF LEN(@StringToSplit) > 0

        INSERT INTO @SplitResult SELECT @counter,@StringToSplit

    SET @counter = @counter + 1

    RETURN
END
GO

-- You use it like this
SELECT S.id, T.item FROM #settings AS S CROSS APPLY Split(S.setting, '|') AS T
```

[image: Split result]

2) Split the settings and separate the setting name from it's value.

```
SELECT 
    S.id, 
    T.item,
    SettingName = SUBSTRING(T.item, 1, CHARINDEX('=', T.item, 1) - 1), -- -1 to not include the "="
    SettingValue = SUBSTRING(T.item, CHARINDEX('=', T.item, 1) + 1, 100) -- +1 to not include the "="
FROM 
    #settings AS S 
    CROSS APPLY Split(S.setting, '|') AS T
```

[image: Value separation]

3) Pivot the known settings by name:

```
;WITH SplitValues AS
(
    SELECT 
        S.id, 
        SettingName = SUBSTRING(T.item, 1, CHARINDEX('=', T.item, 1) - 1), -- -1 to not include the "="
        SettingValue = SUBSTRING(T.item, CHARINDEX('=', T.item, 1) + 1, 100) -- +1 to not include the "="
    FROM 
        #settings AS S 
        CROSS APPLY Split(S.setting, '|') AS T
)
SELECT
    P.id,
    P.setting1,
    P.setting2,
    P.setting3
FROM
    SplitValues AS S
    PIVOT (
        MAX(S.SettingValue) FOR SettingName IN ([setting1], [setting2], [setting3])
    ) AS P
```

[image: Final result]

Comment: Hi Ezequiel López, thanks for you suggestion, as Sean Lange mentioned I should have a look at a better split value, so I'll take this one in test too. At first sight your code is much longer and does the same. But in some cases there are more than 100 columns filled, so performance is an issue. I will try your suggestion and bump it in the question text if it's faster.

Comment: Keep in mind that if you have more than 100 columns, it would be wise to store them as rows and normalize them, as Sean Lange mentioned. Specially if most of them don't have all their values, you would have a huge table full of NULLs.

Answer (score 0):

For set columns (photo properties) I agree with columns in a row
Use the proper type e.g. DateTime, Int, Numeric as you can search on range, sort,  and it is just more efficient.

I know you asked for SQL but I would do this in .NET as you are going to need to do some clean up like remove comma from an integer.  In real life read lines from a file so you can leave the command (insert) open.

```
public static void ParsePhoto(string photo)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(photo))
    {
        photo = @"FullName = D:\8.jpg | FolderName = D:\| FileName = 8.jpg | Size = 7284351 | Extension =.jpg | datePictureTaken = 10 - 3 - 2017 11:53:38 | ApertureValue = 2 | DateTime = 10 - 3 - 2017 11:53:38 | DateTimeDigitized = 10 - 3 - 2017 11:53:38 | DateTimeOriginal = 10 - 3 - 2017 11:53:38 | ExposureTime = 0,0025706940874036 | FocalLength = 3,65 | GPSAltitude = 43 | GPSDateStamp = 10 - 3 - 2017 0:00:00 | Model = QCAM - AA | ShutterSpeedValue = 8,604";
    }
    List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> kvp = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
    foreach(string s in photo.Trim().Split(new char[] {'|'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    {
        string[] sp = s.Split(new char[] { '=' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        if (sp.Count() == 2)
        {
            kvp.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(sp[0].Trim(), sp[1].Trim()));
        }
        else
        {
            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("bad photo");
        }
    }
    foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in kvp)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"{pair.Key} = {pair.Value}");
        //build up and execute insert statement here
    }
    Debug.WriteLine("Done");
}

FullName = D:\8.jpg
FolderName = D:\
FileName = 8.jpg
Size = 7284351
Extension = .jpg
datePictureTaken = 10 - 3 - 2017 11:53:38
ApertureValue = 2
DateTime = 10 - 3 - 2017 11:53:38
DateTimeDigitized = 10 - 3 - 2017 11:53:38
DateTimeOriginal = 10 - 3 - 2017 11:53:38
ExposureTime = 0,0025706940874036
FocalLength = 3,65
GPSAltitude = 43
GPSDateStamp = 10 - 3 - 2017 0:00:00
Model = QCAM - AA
ShutterSpeedValue = 8,604
```

Comment: That's no problem, I can test/use this in the SSIS package this solution uses anyway. Thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

If performance is important you can get this done easily without a splitter function, casting the data as XML or doing any pivoting. This technique is commonly referred to as the [Cascading CROSS APPLY](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/97545/). The code is a little more verbose but the performance pay-off is amazing. First the solution:

```
SELECT 
  id, 
  setting1 = substring(setting, s1.p+1, x1.x),
  setting2 = substring(setting, s2.p+1, x2.x),
  setting3 = substring(setting, s3.p+1, x3.x)
FROM #settings t
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (nullif(charindex('setting1=', t.setting),0)+8)) s1(p)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (nullif(charindex('setting2=', t.setting),0)+8)) s2(p)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (nullif(charindex('setting3=', t.setting),0)+8)) s3(p)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (isnull(nullif(charindex('|',t.setting,s1.p),0)-s1.p-1, 1))) x1(x)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (isnull(nullif(charindex('|',t.setting,s2.p),0)-s2.p-1, 1))) x2(x)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (isnull(nullif(charindex('|',t.setting,s3.p),0)-s3.p-1, 1))) x3(x);
```

Note the execution plans:

[image]

I don't have time to put together a performance test but, based on the execution plans - the cascading cross apply technique is roughly 44,000 times faster.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
declare @table table (id int, setting varchar(100))
insert into @table values
(1,'setting1=a|setting2=b|setting3=c'),
(2,'setting1=d|setting2=e'),
(3,'setting1=f|setting3=g'),
(4,'setting2=h')

select id, 
       case when charindex('setting1=',setting) = 0 then null else SUBSTRING(setting, charindex('setting1=',setting) + 9, 1) end [setting1],
       case when charindex('setting2=',setting) = 0 then null else SUBSTRING(setting, charindex('setting2=',setting) + 9, 1) end [setting2],
       case when charindex('setting3=',setting) = 0 then null else SUBSTRING(setting, charindex('setting3=',setting) + 9, 1) end [setting3]
from @table
```